# What's that between Matt Damon and Jimmy Kimmel?

Tags: academy-awards, jimmy-kimmel-live

All the way through the Oscar ceremony last night, Jimmy Kimmel was making jokes about Matt Damon.

Clearly it was some kind of joke, but I'm not familiar with the background.  What is the story behind this "feud"?

Comment: Clearly, it's light-hearted. I'm also curious about the genesis of how this comedic "feud" came about. I'm guessing something came up on Jimmy's show and they kept on running with it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with movies....

Comment: Isn't the network called Movies & TV? (It clearly is TV, isn't it? And why would there be an "academy-award" tag, if it's off topic?

Comment: @cde Fundamentally it is a question about the Oscar ceremony, clearly on-topic.

Comment: @cde - and it's a recurring theme on Jimmy Kimmel Live!, which is a TV show.

Comment: And yet another question where there is clearly no effort. [A simple Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=matt%20damon%20jimmy%20kimmel) would reveal everything you need to know.

Comment: Sarah Silverman was at one point included:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eSfoF6MhgLA&list=RDeSfoF6MhgLA

Comment: Not *every* question about some random event happening during the Oscar ceremony is on-topic, neither is any question marignally related to them, [tag:academy-awards] tag notwithstanding. The existence of a tag doesn't magically make all kinds of questions on-topic and this seems entirely related to current events and in no way related to the respective persons and their bodies of work, neither is it about the workings of the Oscars. Questions about news and current events are off-topic, as specified in the [help center](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Some of the comments here are missing a fundamental point. This isn't a news item, and it's not about the personal lives of actors.  This is a plot point of a scripted TV show ("Jimmy Kimmel Live!") that has carried over into the scripted elements of a TV special (the Oscars).  It is about fiction.  I can't see why this would be off-topic.

Comment: @BenMiller You might want to rephrase the question accordingly then.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Done.  My suggested edit has been submitted.

Comment: It completely changes the meaning of the question and assumes things that the OP hasn't said. That's a destructive edit.

Comment: Case in point, op does not know if it's real or a joke. Your edit changes their meaning completely.

Comment: The edit doesn't really change the meaning of the question. I'm not sure if it really makes it reopenable and I doubt it, but it seemed to improve the question at least, especialy in a direction *towards* a possible reopening, even if not completely thereto. In its previous form it seemed doomed anyway.

Comment: I asked the original question and I approve the edit.

Comment: At this point it really doesn't matter if it's reopened or not, IMO. Even if no more answers are allowed, the question was asked and satisfactorily answered. The Q&A both got upvotes (and can continue to do so) and can still receive witty & pithy comments.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

*People* magazine did an article about this "feud" that you can [read online](http://people.com/movies/matt-damon-jimmy-kimmel-feud/). Basically it was a throw away joke that they thought was funny so it became a recurring thing. There are lots more details in the article but the meat of it is here:

> “We had a bad show … The guests were bad, and I was feeling pretty bad about myself at the end of the program,” Kimmel told NPR in 2013. “And I decided to say, for the amusement of one of our producers who was standing next to me … ‘I want to apologize to Matt Damon. We ran out of time.’ … And he got a kick out of it, the producer, so I just started doing it every night to amuse him.”
>
> And even though he only said Damon’s name because it’s the first A-lister he thought of, the joke stuck after the December 2005 episode. The host then spent about a year closing his show with the same apology to Damon before the actor himself came on to participate in a fake fight in 2006 after he finally makes it on the show and the host cuts him off.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I still think it's on topic because all this stuff is playing out on Kimmel's TV shows and others like tonite's aforementioned Academy Awards.

Answer (score 4):

As a Coda to Erik's answer:

After a while Matt Damon got in on the joke. They'd show clips of him backstage acting all ticked that he was bumped. It sort of snowballed from there. They'd start doing bits where Damon snuck onto the set, or even took over the show. In 2008 Kimmel's then-girlfriend Sarah Silverman got in on the act by presenting on the show an entire song about how she was cheating on him with Damon.

Because we know its not true, its kind of funny. Also, its good publicity for both of them, so they keep doing it. Time.com has [a good article up](http://time.com/4473441/jimmy-kimmel-matt-damon-feud-history-timeline/) going into more detail, including lots of youtube clips.